# How to sort NSDate in descending order from Parse in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am looking to get the Parse data of my **past** meetings. My issue is I want to see the most recent events first. If I fetch the data with following code, am getting it in ascending order. i.e. most recent meeting goes to the last and the oldest comes first.

```
//let oldDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -123456789.0) 

let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    //query.whereKey("EventSTDTime", greaterThan: oldDate)
    query.whereKey("EventSTDTime", lessThan: NSDate())
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object, error) -> Void in
        if object != nil
        {
            if(object!.count != 0)
            {
                for messageObject in object! {
                    let meetingName:String! = (messageObject as! PFObject)["MeetingName"] as? String
                }
            }
       }
```

I tried with removing the comment, I still dont get any difference. I want the most recent meetings at first and then oldest event at the last.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your query.

```
[query addDescendingOrder:@"EventSTDTime"];
```